# ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: security, magento, ssh, sh, putty

I've gotten

> PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh

to install properly, but when I try to install

> PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

I get the error,

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.rej
```

I'm using this command,

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh
```

What do I need to do differently?  This is super frustrating; any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:  I noticed it ask for confirmation "Assume -R? [n]" so I added the -R to confirm the action like this.

sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh -R
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh -R

And they both came out successfully. 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... 
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Which version you are using , because 
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh patch is already there in Magento 1.9.0.1

One can manually check these files also , with (-) sign - in file they have remove the code and with (+) - they have added new code

```
__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
index c698108..6e256bb 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
@@ -444,7 +444,7 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboar
             }
             return self::API_URL . '?' . implode('&', $p);
         } else {
-            $gaData = urlencode(base64_encode(serialize($params)));
+            $gaData = urlencode(base64_encode(json_encode($params)));
             $gaHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
             $params = array('ga' => $gaData, 'h' => $gaHash);
             return $this->getUrl('*/*/tunnel', array('_query' => $params));
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
index eebb471..f9cb8d2 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
@@ -92,7 +92,8 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Actio
         if ($gaData && $gaHash) {
             $newHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
             if ($newHash == $gaHash) {
-                if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
+                $params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)), true);
+                if ($params) {
                     $response = $httpClient->setUri(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::API_URL)
                             ->setParameterGet($params)
```

So if the code is already there in files as suggested above , your patch will not work as it's not needed actually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Debian ? If so, try this:

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh
```

So `sh`  command changed to `./`

Don't forget to login as a file owner.

Comment: Switching from `sh`-ing the file to directly executing it (assuming it has the executable bit set) changes nothing in how the shell script executes.